# Change DataGrid contents in the CellEditEnding event

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have bound the `WPF DataGrid` to an observable collection of view models, where each view model represents each row in the DataGrid. The view model handles the `BeginEdit` and `CellEditEnding` events.

In one of the scenarios, I want to change the contents of the observable collection in the `CellEditEnding` event. But, I cant do this because the DataGrid is still in edit mode and if I try to add / remove items from the observable collection an exception is thrown and it causes my application to crash.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Dispatch** it please.

In the `CellEditEnding` handler invoke your code with the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` method.

Also you said

> The view model handles the BeginEdit and CellEditEnding events.

If you are using pure MVVM then this is forbidden. MVVM implements events via `Delegate/Relay Commands`.

Comment: I will try using the dispatcher. I am using a behavior attached on the data grid to invoke BeginEdit() and EndEdit() on the view model when the data grid BeginEdit and CellEditEnding events are raised.